# Constructor error: Expected '(' but got identifier solidity

Tags: solidity, constructor

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
```

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract PokemonFactory {

```
struct Pokemon {
  uint id;
  string name;
}

struct Type {
  string name;
  string description;
}

struct Habilities {
  string name;
  string description;
}

struct Weaknesses {
  string name;
  string description;
}

Pokemon[] private pokemons;
Habilities[] private hability;
Type[] private pokemontype;
Weaknesses[] private weaknesses;

mapping (uint => Type) public pokemonType;
mapping (uint => address) public pokemonToOwner;
mapping (address => uint) ownerPokemonCount;

event eventNewPokemon(string message, string name, uint indexed id);

constructor () public {
  string[5] data; 
  // Expected '(' but got identifier solidity(2314)
  function typepo () public returns (string[5] memory) {
    data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    return data;
  }
}

function createPokemon (string memory _name, uint _id) public {
  require(_id > 0, "El id debe ser mayor a 0");
  require(bytes(_name).length > 2, "El nombre no debe estar vacio y ser mayor a 2 caracteres");

  pokemons.push(Pokemon(_id, _name));
  pokemonToOwner[_id] = msg.sender;
  ownerPokemonCount[msg.sender]++;
    
  emit eventNewPokemon("Nuevo Pokemon Creado", _name, _id);
}

function getAllPokemons() public view returns (Pokemon[] memory) {
  return pokemons;
}

function getResult() public pure returns(uint product, uint sum){
  uint a = 1; 
  uint b = 2;
  product = a * b;
  sum = a + b;
```

}

}

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake in the code is that you are trying to declare a function inside the constructor. This is not allowed in Solidity, and it will result in a compilation error. Functions can not be declared inside another function or constructor.

Here's an example of how you can fix the code to declare the function outside the constructor:

```
string[5] public data;

constructor () {
    data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
}

function typepo () public view returns (string[5] memory) {
    return data;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

So you accidentally try to create a function named `typepo()` inside the constructor, which will not work. Just get that function out of the constructor block and it will work fine.

Also, you need to format the code a little bit. The `data` variable needs to be outside the constructor and just the initialization needs to be in the constructor. Try something like this:

```
   string[5] data;

    constructor() {
        data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    }

    function typepo() public view returns (string[5] memory) {
        return data;
    }
```